# Javascript performance array of objects preassignment vs direct use

Tags: javascript

I have a doubt about how can be affected to speed the use of object data arrays, that is, use it directly or preasign them to simple vars.

- I have an array of elements, for example 1000 elements.
- Every array item is an object with 10 properties (for example).
- And finally  I use some of this properties to do 10 calculations.

So I have APPROACH1

```
var nn = myarray.lenght;
var a1,a2,a3,a4 ... a10;
var cal1,cal2,.. cal10
for (var x=0;x<nn;x++)
{ // assignment
  a1=my_array[x].data1;
   ..
  a10 =my_array[x].data10; 

  // calculations
  cal1 = a1*a10 +a2*Math.abs(a3);
  ... 
  cal10 = (a8-a7)*4 +Math.sqrt(a9);
}
```

And APPROACH2

```
var nn = myarray.lenght;

    for (var x=0;x<nn;x++)
    {  

      // calculations
      cal1 = my_array[x].data1*my_array[x].data10 +my_array[x].data2*Math.abs(my_array[x].data3);
      ... 
      cal10 = (my_array[x].data8-my_array[x].data7)*4 +Math.sqrt(my_array[x].data9);
    }
```

Assign a1 ... a10 values from my_array and then make calculations is faster than make the calculations using my_array[x].properties; or the right is the opposite ?????

I dont know how works the 'js compiler' ....

Comment: you can compare your scripts performance in http://jsperf.com

Comment: Can you add an example of the populated array of elements? Jsperf...

Comment: Do you experience any performance problems? If not, what makes you think you need to optimize this part?

Comment: To answer the question: array access `[x]` is highly optimized in all JS engines, there's no need for any temporary variables.

Comment: I know jsperf. However my question is easy: is it worth to pre-assing object array data ? I'm going to write a lot of code and I want to know which approach is better to start my job ....

Comment: @georg But I have two acceses. One to the array , second to the objet.propertie ... So maybe the preassigment approach can be better ?

Comment: @civiltomain: maybe yes, maybe no. Again, until you have a problem, there's no point to seek for a solution. If you're just curious, jsperf it and let us know (self-answering a question would be appropriate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kind of short answer is: it depends on your javascript engine, there is no right and wrong here, only "this has worked in the past" and "this don't seem to speed thing up no more".

<tl;dr> If i would not run a jsperf test, i would go with "Cached example" 1 example down: </tl;dr>

A general rule of thumb is(read: was) that if you are going to use an element in an array more then once, it could be faster to cache it in a local variable, and if you were gonna use a property on an object more then once it should also be cached.

Example:
You have this code:

```
// Data generation (not discussed here)
function GetLotsOfItems() {
    var ret = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        ret[i] = { calc1: i * 4, calc2: i * 10, calc3: i / 5 };
    }
    return ret;
}

// Your calculation loop
var myArray = GetLotsOfItems();
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    var someResult = myArray[i].calc1 + myArray[i].calc2 + myArray[i].calc3;
}
```

Depending on your browser (read:this REALLY depends on your browser/its javascript engine) you could make this faster in a number of different ways.
You could for example cache the element being used in the calculation loop

Cached example:

```
// Your cached calculation loop
var myArray = GetLotsOfItems();
var element;
var arrayLen = myArray.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLen ; i++) {
    element = myArray[i];
    var someResult = element.calc1 + element.calc2 + element.calc3;
}
```

You could also take this a step further and run it like this:

```
var myArray = GetLotsOfItems();
var element;
for (var i = myArray.length; i--;) { // Start at last element, travel backwards to the start
    element = myArray[i];
    var someResult = element.calc1 + element.calc2 + element.calc3;
}
```

What you do here is you start at the last element, then you use the condition block to see if i > 0, then AFTER that you lower it by one (allowing the loop to run with i==0 (while --i would run from 1000 -> 1), however in modern code this is usually slower because you will read an array backwards, and reading an array in the correct order usually allow for either run-time or compile-time optimization (which is automatic, mind you, so you don't need to do anything for this work), but depending on your javascript engine this might not be applicable, and the backwards going loop could be faster..

However this will, by my experience, run slower in chrome then the second "kinda-optimized" version (i have not tested this in jsperf, but in an CSP solver i wrote 2 years ago i ended caching array elements, but not properties, and i ran my loops from 0 to length.

You should (in most cases) write your code in a way that makes it easy to read and maintain, caching array elements is in my opinion as easy to read (if not easier) then non-cached elements, and they might be faster (they are, at least, not slower), and they are quicker to write if you use an IDE with autocomplete for javascript :P